# Open SSL vs Secure SSL

Tags: android, ssl

Could any one let me know what difference between open SSL and Secure SSL.

Acutely i have posted new Android application at play store, it uses remote API.

At API server i have successfully installed the secure SSL. 
But Still i am being rejected and support team says your application has "OpenSSL vulnerabilities in your apps".

I am using oovoo SDK in my application, may be it contains above issue.

But here just i would like to know difference between Open and secure SSL.

Thanks!

Comment: What is "Secure SSL"? Is it a real thing at all because this effectively translates to "Secure Secure Socket Layer"? Could you please add a reference? Or do you mean "Secure Transport", i.e. the TLS implementation from Apple?

Comment: here Secure SSL, i meant by purchased SSL from godaddy,  installed at my API server. So transmission b/w android app and API server could be in encrypted formate.

Comment: OpenSSL is the programming library used to implement TLS, i.e. the actual encryption and authentication. Whereas your "secure SSL" is just the certificate you install at the server.  And the reason the application got rejected is because you use the OpenSSL library wrong. Typically wrong usage means that you disable certificate validation in some way. And no certificate will help if the application does not check it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secure SSL: It is a certificate you install at the server.

OpenSSL:  It's a software library used to implement the TLS(Transport Layer Security) and SSL (Secure Sockets Layer)

Answer (score -1):

First of all try use these command

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I think after enabling the OpenSSL in the server you have just installed the Self Signed Certificate SSL, which is already inbuilt in the server.
OpenSSL is a general purpose cryptography library that provides an open source implementation of the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) and Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocols.

TO remove this error you have to purchase the SSL certificate service from trusted companies like GoDaddy, Symantec, Comodo etc. These companies are globally recognized by all browsers and all big companies.

And there is no specific term like secure SSL.

You just need to follow these steps:
1. Generate the Certificate signing request (CSR) in you server and provide the information, which asked in the steps to generate CSR.
2. Then copy or upload that CSR code in your legit ssl service provider company.
3. After few minutes you will get the ssl certificate files.
4. Upload the files in relative folder, it depends which server you are using.

**If you are using Ubuntu Server the follow these steps:**

**1.Log in to your server via your terminal ssh**

**2.At the prompt, type the following command:**

Please make sure to replace server name with your server name.

```
openssl req –new –newkey rsa:2048 –nodes –keyout server.key –out server.csr
```

**You've now started the process for generating the following two files:**

**Private-Key File:** Used to generate the CSR and later to secure and verify connections using the certificate.

**Certificate Signing Request (CSR) file:** Used to order your SSL certificate and later to encrypt messages that only its corresponding private key can decrypt.

**3.When prompted for the Common Name (domain name), type the fully qualified domain (FQDN) **example: abcdfgh.com** for the site that you are going to secure.**

Note: If you're generating an Apache CSR for a Wildcard certificate, make sure your common name starts with an asterisk (e.g., *.example.com).

**4.When prompted, type your organizational information, beginning with your Country name.**

Note: You may have already set up default information.

Now, your OpenSSL .csr file is created.

**5.Order Your SSL/TLS Certificate**

**6.Open the .csr file you created with a text editor.**

**7.Copy the text, including the -----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- and -----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- tags, and paste it in to the SSL provider company (Godaddy or Comodo) order form.**

Save Private Key

**8.Save (back up) the generated .key file. You need it later to install your SSL certificate.**

**Install Certificate**

**9.After you've received your SSL certificate from Provider (Godaddy or Comodo), you can install it on your server.**

Ubuntu with Apache2: Installing and Configuring Your SSL Certificate
If you still need to create a certificate signing request (CSR) and order your certificate, see Ubuntu with Apache2: How to Use OpenSSL to Create Your CSR.

After Provider (Godaddy or Comodo) have validated and issued your SSL certificate, you can install it on your Ubuntu with Apache2 server (where the CSR was generated) and configure the server to use the certificate.

**10.How to Install and Configure the SSL Certificate on Your Ubuntu Server with Apache2**
Copy the certificate files to your server.

Log in to your Provider (Godaddy or Comodo) account and download the intermediate (abcdf.com.crt) and your primary certificate (abcdf.com.crt) files.

**11.Copy these files, along with the .key file you generated when creating the CSR, to the directory on the server where you keep your certificate and key files.**

Note: Make them readable by root only to increase security.

**12.Find the Apache configuration file you need to edit.**

The location and name of the configuration file can vary from server to server-especially if you're using a special interface to manage your server configuration.

**13.The Ubuntu server with Apache2 main configuration file for your SSL/TLS site is typically found in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/your_site_name.**

**14.If it's not found in the 'sites-enabled' directory, run the command below.**

```
sudo a2ensite your_site_name
Open the file with a text editor and find the <VirtualHost> blocks that contain the Apache settings.
```

**15.Identify the SSL  block you need to configure.**

If your site needs to be accessible through both secure (https) and non-secure (http) connections, you need two separate files in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/. One file is for port 80 and the other file is for port 443. Configure both files for SSL as described in step 4.

If your site only needs to be accessed securely, configure the existing virtual host for SSL as described in step 4.

**16.Configure the  block for the SSL-enabled site**

Below is a very simple example of a virtual host configured for SSL. The parts listed in blue are the parts you must add to configure the SSL configuration; they may be spread throughout the file.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your_domain_name.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your_private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/snakeoil.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure to adjust the file names to match your certificate files.

SSLCertificateFile is your DigiCert certificate file (e.g., your_domain_name.crt).

SSLCertificateKeyFile is the .key file generated when you created the CSR (e.g., your_private.key).

SSLCertificateChainFile is the DigiCert intermediate certificate file (e.g., DigiCertCA.crt)

Note: If the SSLCertificateChainFile directive doesn't work, try using the SSLCACertificateFile directive instead.

Test your Apache2 configuration file before restarting.

As a best practice, check your Apache2 configuration file for any errors before restarting Apache.

Caution: Apache2 won't start again if your configuration files have syntax errors.

Run the following command to test your configuration file (on some systems, it's apache2ctl):

```
apachectl configtest
Restart Apache2
```

You can use apachectl commands to stop and start Apache2 with SSL support.

```
apachectl stop
apachect1 start
```

I hope this information should be helpful to you.